Recent Block Hash Issue with Multiple transactions
I want to do multiple transactions at one, When I tried to execute the transactions it shows that block-hash not found, I guess due to expiration of the block.
How can I overcome this issue? Sometimes it will take sometime to sign the transactions, so those are failing.

You may simply need to fetch a new blockhash in between transactions to give each one maximum time for the user to sign before sending.
